# JUnit using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a a service class named Service.class and two classes named A.class and B.class 
Service class has a method which calls methods based on object of classes A & B. then how can i create mockito object of A & B so that I can pass that mockito object in the service class method.Which is needed for the JUnit testing. 
eg. Service.class

```
    class Service {
            A a;
            Response response;

            public Service(){

            }

            public Service(A a, B b){
                this.a= a;
                this.b = b;
            } 

            public Respose test(InputStream i,InputStream i1){
                InputStream inStreamA = a.method1(i,i1);
                Response response=  response.method2(inStreamA);

                return response;
            }


and in Response.class

   public Response method2(InputStream i1)){
     return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Edit:
My JUnit Class
I have created both classes

```
     A mockedA = mock(A.class);
        Response mockedResponse = mock(Response.class);

         when(mockedA.method1(new ByteArrayInputStream("test").getByte()).thenReturn(InputStream);
         when(mockedResponse.method2(new ByteArrayInputStream("test").getByte()).thenReturn(Res);

        Service service = new Service(mockedA , mockedResponse );
        Response i = service.test(new ByteArrayInputStream("test").getByte(), new ByteArrayInputStream("test1").getByte());

       System.out.print(response);  
       assertEquals(200,response.getStatus()); 

// but here i am getting null pointer
```

Comment: Mockito.mock(A.class) same goes for B. It will give you the mocked object. Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: @ppuskar Please see my Edit I did that already but was getting null

Comment: after mocking use this assertNotNull(mockedA) and for mockedB as well. It will let you confirm if the mocked object is null or Null pointer is due to the methods of mocked classes

Comment: @ppuskar i checked with assertNotNull(mockedA) is not null

Comment: @ppuskar please check the edit i have changed the question code

Comment: Exactly which line is giving you the null pointer exception?  And what is this variable called `response`?  I can't see where you've declared it; so please show ALL of your code, not just the parts that YOU think matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply mock them in your test.

First add following import :
`import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;`

then in your code

```
 //You can mock concrete classes, not only interfaces
 A mockedA = mock(A.class);
 B mockedB = mock(A.class);

 //stubbing
 when(mockedA.method1(any(InputStream.class))).thenReturn(null);
 when(mockedB.method2(any(InputStream.class))).thenReturn(null);
```

And then pass them as arguments to Service constructor.

Without stubbing, your mocked class methods will return nulls, by stubbing you can specify what value they should return.

Code below shows that test method returns 400

```
  A mockedA = mock(A.class);
  B mockedB = mock(B.class);

  when(mockedA.method1(new ByteArrayInputStream("test".getBytes()))).thenReturn(null);
  when(mockedB.method2(new ByteArrayInputStream("test".getBytes()))).thenReturn(null);

  Service service = new Service(mockedA , mockedB );
  String i = service.test(new ByteArrayInputStream("test".getBytes()));

  System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: I modified your code, please check it and draw conclusions.

Comment: please check the edit i have changed the question code